# Invoke a one-time (static) initialization in a prototype spring bean

Tags: java, spring

I currently have the following Spring bean definitions:

```
<bean id="myAwesomeBeanSetup" class="com.beanpckg.SuperBean" scope="singleton" init-method="doPreStep"/>
<bean id="myAwesomeBean" class="com.beanpckg.SuperBean" scope="prototype" depends-on="myAwesomeBeanSetup"/>
```

Essentially, what I need is to run SuperBean.doPreStep only once, but still have a fresh instance of SuperBean for subsequent calls. Since I have a lot of beans with such structure, I was wondering, is there a more elegant way to achieve this without having two lines of definitions? Note that there could also be "cross-bean" dependencies, for example:

```
<bean id="myAwesomeBeanSetup" class="com.beanpckg.SuperBean" scope="singleton" init-method="doPreStep"/>
<bean id="myAwesomeBean2Setup" class="com.beanpckg.SuperBean2" scope="singleton" init-method="doPreStep"/>
<bean id="myAwesomeBean" class="com.beanpckg.SuperBean" scope="prototype" depends-on="myAwesomeBeanSetup,myAwesomeBean2Setup"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code in the static initialization block as following:

```
public class SuperBean {
    // …
    static {
        doPreStep();
    }

    public static void doPreStep() {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want a pure `Spring` solution, you can implement a `FactoryBean` and invoke the `doPreStep()` in its init method as following:

```
public class SuperFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SuperBean>{

    public void init() {
        SuperBean.doPreStep();
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    public SuperBean getObject(){
        return new SuperBean();
    }

    public Class<SuperBean> getObjectType() { 
        return SuperBean.class ; 
    }
}
```

And define your bean as following:

```
<bean id="myAwesomeBean" class="com.beanpckg.SuperFactoryBean" init-method="init">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to achieve within your awesome superclass:

For me this would be the perfect usecase of having a separate singleton with the common code and autowire it into your prototype.

Since your init will not be different per bean why having it in a superclass?